# How to remove tags with different heads and tails in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a webpage using BeautifulSoup. When I cleaned the html I encounter a tag with different head and tails:

```html
<!-- BEGIN mobile-middle-rectangle -->
<div class="mobile-bottom-rectangle hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">             
    
                            <div class="textrule">
                               <span>advertisement</span>
                            </div>
    
                            <!-- /1002721/ScienceDaily_Mobile_Bottom_Rectangle -->
                            <div id="adslot-mobile-bottom-rectangle">
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    googletag.cmd.push(function() { 
                                        deployads.push(function() { deployads.gpt.display("adslot-mobile-bottom-rectangle") }); 
                                    });
                                </script>
                            </div>              
    
                            <hr class="hrrule">
    
                        </div>
<!-- END mobile-middle-rectangle -->
```

How can I remove it?

Comment: What do you mean by _different head and tails_ ?

Comment: I mean the opening and closing tag are different:

<!-- BEGIN mobile-middle-rectangle -->

<!-- END mobile-middle-rectangle -->

Comment: That’s a comment, I’m not sure how/if BeautifulSoup handles them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you should use regex.
If you want to remove all the tags starting and ending with these types of tags (`<!-- BEGIN/END whatever -->`), use this:

```
re.sub("<!-- BEGIN.*>\n(<?.+>?\s+)+<!-- END.*-->", "", html)
```

If you want to save the content between these tags, use this:

```
cleaned = re.sub(r"<!-- BEGIN.*>\n((<?.+>?\s+)+)<!-- END.*-->", r"\1", html)
```